# Google Api Error: Invalid request - Prices are missing for the following billable countries: LB

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play

I developed an app and now I want to release an update to Play store with expo-cli.
When I type `eas submit -p android --latest` I received the following result: https://ibb.co/D5hPF6Y

How can I solve it?

Comment: There is an error message saying what is wrong in your screenshot. So just add prices for that country?

Comment: @FerryKranenburg The error is the following `Google Api Error: Invalid request - Prices are missing for the following billable countries: LB.` I controlled but the country is included with the price.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg What should I do to exclude the country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See for the solution here, to remove that country: https://forums.expo.dev/t/eas-submit-failed-with-google-api-error-invalid-request-prices-are-missing-for-the-following-billable-countries-lb/58581/6